# Route custom page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, routes

I have a page in which I want to display dynamic content. 
Currently it works like:

site.com/c-page.php?brand=hp

How can I call it like:

site.com/brand/hp

Is it necessary to write a rule on htaccess?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you're using Wordpress, You may select the Post name structure for the following structure. This will automatically change in your .htaccess file

Hope this will helps you.
For more information,

- [change WordPress permalink structure](https://yoast.com/change-wordpress-permalink-structure/)

Comment: Thanks Sunil, I have it setup like that, but still have: stie.com/brand/?brand=hp

Reason is I need to generate brand products dynamically and don't want to have 110 pages for this. May be it's my only option tho.